# SAS select random trading dates from another dataset

Tags: sas, random-seed

I am trying to add a 'pseudodate' column to the dataset named 'new1'. The 'pseudodate' column will have randomly chosen trading dates between 01JAN2002 and 31DEC2018. The following code works well. It doesn't take the weekends in the 'pseudodate' but it still adds non trading days. I only want the trading dates. Infact, I created another dataset that has only trading dates. How do I write a SAS code that will randomly pick from the trading dates dataset and put it in the 'new1' dataset in the 'pseudodate'column.

Thanks in advance.

```
data new1;
set new;
format pseudodate yymmddn8.;
  Begdate= '01JAN2002'd;
  enddate= '31DEC2018'd;
  do _i=1 to 1000;
    pseudodate = begdate + (floor((enddate-begdate) * ranuni(457)));
    if weekday(pseudodate) not in (1,7) then leave;
    else call missing(pseudodate);
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a random number in your main data set that's an integer between 1 and the number of days in your trading days.
2. Add a record number to the trading days data
3. Join the data based on the numbers from 1 and 2

If you're only ignoring weekends then why not just generate a random number between x days, and use that to increment it using intnx and the weekday option?

Figure out the number of weekdays between December 2018 and January 2002 and use that as your limit.

Entirely untested:

```
data want;
set new;

nDays =intck('weekdays', '01Jan2002'd, '31Dec2018'd, 'C');

x  = rand('integer', 1, nDays);

randDate = intnx('weekday', '01Jan2002'd, x);

run;
```

Comment: Thanks, Reeza!! Your first solution is very simple and elegant.